# Attempting to add song descriptions to audio while they play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I'm looking to be able to display a description about songs when they are clicked on, that will play through the duration of the song. i.e when the first song is clicked on, whatever small description about the song I want to show will be shown while the song is playing. After the song has ended, the box with the display should disappear.

The HTML for the audio files are :

```
<audio src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js" controls id="audioPlayer">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="current-song"><a href="sounds/Sad%20Mans%20Tongue.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Sad Man's Tongue</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/breed.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Breed</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/creep.mp3">Creep</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Everything%20Zen.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Everything Zen</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Ain't%20It%20Funky%20Now%20Pt%202.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Ain't It Funky Now Pt 2</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/once.mp3">Once</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/killing all the joy.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Killing All The Joy</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/torn.mp3">Torn</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/aftermidnight.mp3">After Midnight</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/X1BetaOWS.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">OWS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/X1 Alpha.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">X1 Alpha</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/undome.mp3">Undo Me</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Low%20.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Low</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/Cumbersome.mp3">Cumbersome</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Thru%20Your%20Window%20.mp3">Thru Your Window</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Reconsider%20Baby.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Reconsider Baby</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/4lee.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">4LEE</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/show%20biz%20kids.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Show Biz Kids</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/show%20biz%20guitar.mp3">Show Biz Guitar</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Voodoo%20Child.mp3">Voodoo Child</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/saveme.mp3">Save Me</a></li>-->

</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="audioPlayer.js"></script>
<script>
    audioPlayer();
</script>
```

The audioplayer.js I'm using is :

```
function audioPlayer(){
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
        });

        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
            currentSong++;
            if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play;
        });
    }// JavaScript Document
```

I believe the way to solve it would be to have something included in the audioplayer.js file when the current-song class is added, though I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the details are readily available for each of your songs, yes, you could modify your audioPlayer.js to display information specific to the current song.

```
CSS
.song-info {
  display:none; // hidden by default
}

HTML
<div id="song-info">
  Nothing playing.
</div>

JS
let currentDescription = descriptions[currentSong]
$('#song-info').css('display', 'inline');
$('#song-info').text(currentDescription);
```

In the above JS it's assumed that 'descriptions' is the handle to a map of song descriptions, matching indices of the song array referenced in audioPlayer.js (glossing over how and where you'd get such a map from). It retrieves the description text for the current song and modifies the contents of the '#song-info' div. You'd want to include these lines in your audioPlayer.js file wherever currentSong is assigned a new value.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something along these lines but just wasn't sure how to execute it. I'll work on figuring out the rest now :)

Comment: And got it! Had take a couple days off from it but I was able to simply use what you wrote, created an array with the descriptions tag and everything ran beautifully! Thank you!